# Add Single quotes where string contains comma in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a string which contains values like

```
var string = A,B,C
```

Here I want to add single quote for each comma value, expected result should be as below

```
output = 'A','B','C'
```

My angular code is

```
var data = {
           output : this.string.split("\',"),
           }
```

which is giving result as

```
["A,B,C"]
```

Could anyone please help on this how can I get desired output.

Comment: which is giving result as

    ["A,B,C"]

Comment: Do you want the final answer to be a string?

Comment: Yes, final answer must be like this        'A','B','C'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am understanding your code as

```
var string = "A,B,C";  // because string should be in this format.
```

and you just need to replace "\',"  from your split function to "," which will give you an array like this

```
var out = string.split(",");
console.log(out);

[ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]  // this is the output.
```

as split function searches for the given expression and split the string into array.

but if you just want to modify the string without making it in array then you can use the below trick

```
var out = "'" + string.replace(/,/g, "','") + "'";
console.log(out);

'A','B','C'        // result as u mentioned and this is of string type.
```